# Finite dimensional subspaces are always closed

Tags: functional-analysis

If $n$ is a positive integer and $Y$ is an $n$-dimensional sub-space of a complex topological vector space $X$ then I have to prove that $Y$ is closed.

Proof: Let $S$ be the sphere which is the boundary of the open unit ball $B$ of $\Bbb C^n$. Suppose $f : \Bbb C^n \to Y$ is an isomorphism. Put $K=f(S)$. $K$ is compact. Now, $0 \notin K$, and therefore there is a balanced neighbourhood $V$ of $0$ in $X$ which does not intersect $K$.

Now, let $p \in \bar{Y}$. Then Rudin claims that for some $t >0 , p \in tV$. Why ? $V$ is balanced not absorbing

Comment: Your topological vector spaces are Hausdorff?

Comment: **Every** neighbourhood of $0$ in any topological vector space is absorbing. That follows from the continuity of scalar multiplication at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are reading Rudin's book, I suggest you to recheck the first statement of his theorem $1.15$, which says if $r_n \to +\infty$, then 
$$X = \cup_{n=1}^{+\infty}r_n V$$

In particular $p \in \cup_{n=1}^{+\infty}r_n V$ thus $p$ is in one of $r_n V$