# Linear finite-dimensional topological vector space is closed.

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a topological vector space and let $Y \subset X$ be its subspace with $\dim Y < \infty$. The goal is to prove that $Y$ is closed in $X$. I know how to prove this fact when $X$ is endowed with a norm by picking up a Cauchy sequence, but could you please suggest me, how to do it when we do not have any norm?

Comment: What restrictions are in place? Is the scalar field $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, or could it be any topological field? Are topological vector spaces assumed to be Hausdorff? [If not, the assertion doesn't hold, then there are finite-dimensional subspaces that aren't closed.]

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, it is Hausdorff, but I have a feeling that every topological vector space is Hausdorff. About the field: how does it change the answer?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966887/finite-dimensional-subspaces-are-always-closed)

Comment: Some people make Hausdorffness part of the definition of a TVS, others don't. If you don't require the topology to be Hausdorff, then the indiscrete topology makes a vector space a TVS. And that's only Hausdorff if the space is $\{0\}$. About the scalar field, with the usual topologies $\mathbb{R}$ is a topological $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. But a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-subspace is not closed - unless it's $\{0\}$ - but dense.

Comment: @DanielFischer Suppose $0,a\in X$ and consider $A = X\setminus\{x\}$. Note that $A$ is an open neighbourhood of $0$. Then there exist two neighbourhoods of $0$, namely $P$ and $Q$ such that $P+Q \subset W$. This works since all the operations in a topological vector space are continuous. But then $x-Q$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, and also $P$ and $x-Q$ are disjoint. Hence, $X$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: $A$ is only open if the space is $T_1$, and a $T_1$ TVS is Hausdorff (since a TVS is automatically $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$, as a uniform space). So for TVS, it is equivalent to require $T_1$ (singletons are closed) or $T_2$ (Hausdorff).

Comment: @DanielFischer Okay, probably it is the time to define a TVS:
1) Point is a closed set;
2) Vector space operations are continuous.

Comment: And some people only require 2). Together, 1) and 2) imply Hausdorffness.